# Problema na leitura de strings

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo um algoritmo que recebe o número de *casos*, seguidamente um *nome* com *sobrenome*, uma *cor* e um *tamanho*.

Ele deve fazer uma comparação e imprimi-los ordenados por *cor* em ordem ascendente, *tamanho* em ordem descendente e os *nomes* em ordem ascendentes.

Essa parte das comparações esta funcionando bem acredito eu, eu acho que o problema está na leitura dos dados que sempre tem algum sendo pulado.

Exemplo de entrada e saída:

```
3
Maria Jose
branco P
Cezar Torres Mo
branco P
Baka Lhau
vermelho P
0

// A saída ficaria:

branco P Cezar Torres Mo
branco P Maria Jose
vermelho P Baka Lhau
```

O código que fiz é esse:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct             // Estrutura que contem as variáveis
{
    char nome[100];
    char cor[100];
    char tam[100];
}camisetas;

camisetas pessoa[100];     // Método de acesso a estrutura

int casos, d = 0, A;

int comparaNome(const void * a, const void * b){

    int r;
    //r = strcmp((*(struct camisetas*)a).nome, (*(struct camisetas*)b).nome);
    const camisetas *elemA = a;
    const camisetas *elemB = b;

    if (elemA -> cor == elemB -> cor){
        if(elemA -> tam == elemB -> tam) {
            return strcmp(elemA -> nome, elemB -> nome);
        }
        else return (elemA -> tam[0] - elemB -> tam[0]) * (-1);
    }
    else{
        return elemA -> cor[0] - elemB -> cor[0];
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int count, i, number;    // Variáveis auxiliares
    //char* array_string [number];

    scanf("%dn", &casos);
    while(casos != 0){       // Comando para encerramento do algoritmo
        fflush(stdin);


        //leitura do numero de casos
        for(i = 0; i < casos; i++)
        {
            scanf("%[^n]", pessoa[i].nome );
            scanf("%s %s", pessoa[i].cor, pessoa[i].tam );
            //fgets(pessoa[i].cor, 15, stdin);
            //fgets(pessoa[i].tam, 10, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        qsort(pessoa, 3 , sizeof(camisetas), comparaNome);

        for(i = 0; i < casos; i++){
            printf("%s %s %sn", pessoa[i].cor, pessoa[i].tam, pessoa[i].nome);
        }
        scanf("%dn", &casos);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Se alguém puder me dizer o erro agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor solução é sempre compilar com Warnings, seu código estava cheio de variáveis inuteis. Para melhor resultado no sorting melhore sua função de comparar, essa minha também é fraca, só vai comparar as primeiras letras de cada campo, mas a leitura está correta. Evite o uso de `fflush` e de variáveis globais.

**Código:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct    
{
   char nome[100];
   char cor[100];
   char tam[100];
} Camisetas;             

int comparaNome(const void *a, const void *b){

   const Camisetas *elemA = a;
   const Camisetas *elemB = b;

   int valor;

   if (elemA->cor[0] > elemB->cor[0]) 
       valor = 1;   
   else if (elemA->cor[0] < elemB->cor[0]) 
       valor = -1;
   else if (elemA->tam[0] < elemB->tam[0])
       valor = 1;
   else if (elemA->tam[0] > elemB->tam[0])
       valor = -1;
   else if (elemA->nome[0] > elemB->nome[0])
       valor = 1;
   else if (elemA->nome[0] < elemB->nome[0])
       valor = -1;
   else
       valor = 0;

   return valor;         
}

void clearStdin(void){  

   int c;

   while(( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && ( c != EOF ));
}

int main(void)
{
  int i, casos;     
  Camisetas pessoa[100];                   

  printf("Digite o número de casos (0 para encerrar): "); 
  scanf(" %d", &casos);
  clearStdin();

  while(casos != 0){ 

    printf("Digite os campos:\n"); 

    for(i = 0; i < casos; i++)
    {
       scanf(" %[^\n]", pessoa[i].nome);

       scanf(" %99s", pessoa[i].cor);

       scanf(" %99s", pessoa[i].tam );     
    }
    qsort(pessoa, casos, sizeof(Camisetas), comparaNome);

    printf("Saída:\n"); 

    for(i = 0; i < casos; i++)
       printf("%s %s %s\n", pessoa[i].cor, pessoa[i].tam, pessoa[i].nome);

       printf("Digite o número de casos (0 para encerrar): ");
       scanf(" %d", &casos);
       clearStdin();    
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Utilize a função `clearStdin` para limpar entradas, coloque sempre um espaço antes dos argumentos do `scanf`. Tente uma função que realmente ordene por ordem alfabética as cores e nomes de forma completa, pois so fiz para as primeiras letras e nomes com primeiras letras iguais não serão ordenados. Isso já que sua maior dúvida era na leitura, aproveite como exercício e reforce esse sorting com loops para comparar cores e nomes por completo.