# problema com leitura de arquivos/ordenação de dados em c

Tags: c

**Olá, meu problema é o seguinte**, no tópico criado pelo Rafael.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24666/rafael

Sobre problema na leitura de strings.

[Problema na leitura de strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69096/problema-na-leitura-de-strings)

Que perguntou sobre ordenação das camisetas em c e então teve a resposta do Rafael Bluhn.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20943/rafael-bluhm

Porem quero usar com arquivos lendo um "arquivo.txt" que irá conter os dados necessários para para passar os valores para a estrutura que está no código do Rafael assim ordenando nome,cor, tamanho e então guardar os dados alterados em outro "arquivo.txt, para então imprimir na tela os dados ordenados.

Tenho a parte de do código para abrir o arquivo mas não consigo colher as informações (que começa com um numero inteiro depois strings) para passar para a estrutura do Rafael.

código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeNovaLinha( char *str );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  FILE *fp;
  int aux, tamanho;
  char buffer[ 256 ];
  char **listaNomes;
  char *nome;

  fp = fopen( "documento.txt", "r" );//digitar o nome do documento que esta na mesma pasta que o programa .c
  //o arquivo deverá conter o "documento.txt" com os dados criados pelo Rafael
  if ( fp == NULL ) {
    printf( "Erro: nao posso abrir o arquivo %s!\n","documento.txt"  );

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
  if ( !fscanf( fp, "%d\n", &tamanho ) ) {
    printf( "Erro: O arquivo deve comecar com um num. inteiro\n" );

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  listaNomes = calloc( tamanho, sizeof( char * ) );
  if ( listaNomes == NULL ) {
    printf( "Erro: nao posso alocar memoria!\n" );

    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
```

```
//preenche a lista de nomes
  for ( aux = 0; aux < tamanho; aux++ ) {
    fgets( buffer, 256, fp );
    removespaco( buffer );
    nome = calloc( strlen( buffer ) + 1, sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy ( nome, buffer );
    listaNomes[ aux ] = nome;
  }
  // fecha o arquivo
  fclose( fp );
  //imprime a lista de nomes
  for ( aux = 0; aux < tamanho; aux++ )
    printf( "%s\n", listaNomes[ aux ] );
```

//libera a memoria alocada
  for ( aux = 0; aux < tamanho; aux++ ) {
    nome = listaNomes[ aux ];
    free( nome );
  }
  free( listaNomes );

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
//função para remover o espaço entre os dados.
void removespaco( char *str )
{
    int tamanho;
    tamanho = strlen( str );
    if ( str[ tamanho -1 ] == '\n' )
      str[ tamanho - 1 ] = '\0';
}`
  Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tenta tirar o '\n' do seu fscanf primeiro, vê se tem algum progresso.

Comment: Olá, no meu caso não irá fazer diferença alguma se tirar o '\n' do fscanf pois só aparecerá uma linha em branco na execução do algoritmo e também quero colocar as informações na estrutura do @rafael-bluhm para ordenar as camisetas.Obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem alguns erros no seu código. 
-> Leitura de inteiro no arquivo.
-> Uso inadequado de ponteiros.
-> Alocação dinâmica incorreta.
`char **listaNomes` só deve ser um ponteiro para ponteiro se for fazer alocação dinâmica de matriz e sua alocação dinâmica esta incorreta. A maneira correta seria:
Primeiro deve ser feita a declaração de um ponteiro para ponteiro do tipo char

```
char **listaNomes;
```

Após isso deve ser feita a alocação desses ponteiros para ponteiros para poder criar então um vetor de vetores que se comporta como uma matriz, assim seria:

```
listaNomes = (char **) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char *));
```

Após isso foi gerado um vetor de ponteiros para ponteiros, então agora deve ser feita a alocação de outros vetores pro tipo char que seria:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++)
    listaNomes[ i ] = (char *) malloc (10 *sizeof(char));
```

Você fez o uso do calloc ao invés do malloc, pois ele inicia toda variável inteira com zero no caso dos tipos numerais e com '\0' para o tipo char.

Para ler um caractere numeral do arquivo você precisa após a leitura passa-lo para a função atoi() que recebe como parâmetro uma string e retorna um inteiro, ou seja:

```
char string[ 2 ] = {'3', '4'};
int num = atoi(str);
num agora guarda 34.
```

Como seu programa deve ordenar os dados por nome,cor e tamanho então você deverá ler a string do arquivo de forma mais dinâmica para então poder separar nome,cor e tamanho em variáveis diferentes. Como no C tudo é possível eu direi que sim é possível ordenar esses dados dentro da string mas será muito mais complicado, então aconselho a você quebrar essa string em variáveis diferentes. Seguindo essas instruções que lhe passei você conseguirá aos poucos modelar seu programa da forma que deseja. Abraço.

Comment: Olá J.Carvalho, obrigado pela resposta, testei aqui no no código mas deu erro de Segmentation fault, e não estou conseguindo unir a parte do arquivo com a ordenação dos dados pois preciso inserir os dados na estrutura e porque o nº 10 no for?.

Comment: Olá Carlos desculpe pela demora, pois bem se caso não tiver resolvido o problema ainda me responda aqui que te ajudarei. Com relação ao for de limite 10 é porque eu imaginei como se fosse uma matriz de 10x10. Imagine a variável tamanho no primeiro malloc guardando o valor 10.